# Is there a ring or field tactic that can solve existential variables in Coq?

Tags: coq, coq-tactic

I know that `ring` and `field` can be used on some equalities like `a + x = b + y`. I am wondering if there is an existential version of it that can determine the value of existential variables?

For example, I have the following:

```
r1, r2 : R
______________________________________(1/1)
r1*r1   + ?s = r2 * r2
```

I can figure out that `?s = r2 * r2 - r1 * r1` solves this. But is there a tactic like `ering` that can let Coq do the computation instead of me doing it manually?